# Alternative to Google Forms?

Tags: google, forms

I'm looking for a web app I can install to allow users to create simple forms, collect responses, and extract the data (e.g. as a CSV spreadsheet) in order to track travel, expenses, etc. Any recommendations for an existing web app, or approaches to implement it (e.g. with Rails)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention a budget, so I'll give you my two favorites:

[Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/features/) - Paid (unless you have small requirements), but awesome. Non-install, but you create the forms there and then install them in your webpage. You can bulk-export to excel or CSV.

[FormTools](http://www.formtools.org/) - Free, open-source, self-hosted. Does all that you need, but isn't as simple to use as Wufoo. However, it is simple to use and I like it a lot.

Comment: Thanks, FormTools is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Ah, it looks like FormTools doesn't actually provide the tools to build a web submission form.

Comment: No sorry David, it doesn't do that, but you can easily build a simple or complex HTML form using WYSIWYG editors offline such as [http://kompozer.net/](Kompozer), or using an online WYSIWYG editor such as [http://www.jotform.com/](JotForm). Then just copy the HTML to your webpage and then change the form handler (action) and the form IDs to the FormTools requirements. You might have to remove some of the jotform javascript if using the online version, but it's the cheapest way I know to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for screwing the links up, here are the correct ones (I missed my editing window of 5 minutes): [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com/) & [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/).

Answer (score 1):

The only form-creating apps I know of are Wufoo, Pandaform, SurveyMonkey, FormSpring.me, and OpinionLab. But of these, only Wufoo will work for what you want (I *think*; you may want to check the other sites to see if they have advanced integration APIs like Wufoo does). However, there is also a [3rd-party Google Form API](http://viatropos.com/blog/introducing-the-google-form-api/) that can customize Google forms via webscraping the formkey and using the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html).

Though unless these services offer additional features you need, I'd just code the forms yourself. It's not that hard (easier than integrating with another service at least), and even if you want flexible forms, there are [ways to do that](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6379/big-specialized-complex-forms-for-ordering-signing-up) as well (and if you don't want to use EAV, you could try [these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/)).

**Edit:**
I just found this too: [custom Google Form via a simple Rails application](https://github.com/mocra/custom_google_forms).